# Does GHC make a new copy of an object when deconstructing and reconstructing it?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, ghc

If I have a type like `data T = T Int String` and a function like so:

```
identity :: T -> T
identity (T a b) = T a b
```

After the deconstruction in the pattern matching, does GHC create a new T object containing references to the same Int and String? Or does it return the exact same object (with the same memory address) it received? I understand they're semantically equivalent, I'm just curious.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In general GHC will allocate a new value rather than reuse the argument in that situation. In this particular case you could write something like

```
f :: T -> T
f t@(T x y) = t
```

to explicitly reuse the argument. Unfortunately, in one of the cases where you'd really want this --

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> Either e a -> Either e b
fmap f (Right x) = Right (f x)
fmap f (Left x) = Left x
```

-- GHC will allocate a new `Left` value, and you can't simply reuse the argument, because the result has a different type. As far as I know there's no way to tell GHC to reuse the argument in this case other than `unsafeCoerce`.

Comment: I see. That's kind of disappointing. I was actually thinking about the case where you have a nested persistent data structure (like a binary tree) and you wanted to insert a value that was already present. You'd need a helper function like 'insert :: (Ord a) => a -> Tree a -> Maybe (Tree a)` that returned a Nothing if the element was already present to avoid reconstructing up the path of the value.

Comment: @Ramith That destroys laziness unfortunately; all of the calls on the path down to the leaf node would have to wait for the ultimate call to return before they'd know whether they're returning a reference to an existing constructor node or allocating a new one, which means forcing the root step forces everything. So if you ever want to choose between those properties (laziness vs avoiding reconstruction of identical trees), then it needs to be explicitly programmed (such as via the Maybe (Tree a) helper) rather than implicit behaviour of the compiler.

Comment: Is `unsafeCoerce` safe in this case? I mean `Either a b` and `Either a c` have the same argument to `Left` so it seems plausible that the `Left` constructor could be coerced without problems (and probably is), however is there any *guarantee* about this?

Answer (score 15):

You can test this easily enough with `-ddump-simpl`. An allocation of a value of an ADT will show up as an application of a data constructor.

In this case, GHC does spot that it can reuse the value, and even that it doesn't have to perform the pattern matching:

```
module I where

data T = T Int String

identity :: T -> T
identity (T a b) = T a b
```

-

```
rwbarton@morphism:/tmp$ ghc -ddump-simpl I
[1 of 1] Compiling I                ( I.hs, I.o )

==================== Tidy Core ====================
Result size of Tidy Core = {terms: 3, types: 3, coercions: 0}

I.identity :: I.T -> I.T
[GblId, Arity=1, Caf=NoCafRefs, Str=DmdType]
I.identity = \ (ds_dHN :: I.T) -> ds_dHN
```

This happens even without optimizations enabled, and it also works on ADTs with more than one constructor.

Comment: The case matching affects strictness. The original specification for `identity` requires it to be strict, so GHC keeps that strictness.